# Comparing two columns of different worksheets and highlight common values in both columns

Tags: excel, excel-2016, vba

I have worksheets named WS1 and WS2. I need to compare Column C of WS1 with Column D of WS2. If both columns contain same values then I need to highlight both the cells of "Column C of WS1" and "Column D of WS2".

Example:

```
Column C of WS1     
500,000.00
260,000.00
65,000.00
30,000.00
46,104.00
530,000.00
350,000.00
55,000.00
7,000.00
2,520.16
30,000.00
210,000.00
650,000.00
10,000.00

Column D of WS2
2520.16
500,000.00
260,000.00
65,000.00
30,000.00
46,104.00
530,000.00
350,000.00
55,000.00
7,000.00
30,000.00
1,827,099.63
210,000.00
650,000.00
10,000.00
```

If values of Column C = Value of Column D then the cell containing same values in both columns is highlighted. My data is not uniform. They may have repetitive values. I am doing it manually right now and it is time-consuming as I have a lot of data to work on. Can you please suggest me.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data starts in row 1 if each sheet, in WS1 column C set up a conditional format formula:

`=IFERROR(MATCH(C1,'WS2'!$D:$D,0),FALSE)`

In column D of WS2 this conditional format formula:

`=IFERROR(MATCH(D1,'WS1'!$C:$C,0),FALSE)`

The IFERROR wrapper is needed because an exact MATCH (last parameter = 0) will return a #N/A error if the value isn't found.  Conditional format formulas must evaluate to TRUE (format applied) or FALSE (format not applied).

Comment: Thank you Sir. But when I select values that has been found in both columns and take their sum, it doesn't show same result. I think this formula ignored the repeated values in each columns. When comparing data "50,000" of each column to another data It takes every "50,000" in account. As I have large number of repeated values in same column, this formula doesn't shows the required output.

Comment: For Eg, If I have 2 2 2 1 1 in Column C and 2 2 1 in Column D, I want to compare both and highlight   2 2 1 as they are common in both columns and leave 2 1 in column C as it does not match.

Comment: The way you question was posted, I took it that you were looking for exact matches for currency amounts.  I didn't realise you were looking for partial text matches.

Comment: I am looking for exact matches for currency amounts and also I want the amounts which has been already matched to be left out. The value in each cell should be matched with only one value of another cell. Leave out the next repeated value to match with next.

Comment: You didn't say that in the question.  I think you need to post a new question clearly setting out **all your requirements**.